# Does higher key sizes correspond to a higher security parameter?

Tags: encryption, public-key, cryptanalysis, brute-force-attack, decryption

If a system provide n bits of security, it is known that the best possible attack against the system would be 2^n (security parameter).
However, why are the key sizes of some cryptosystems much larger than their security parameters?
Is it because these cryptosystems have a weak and vulnerable algorithm?

Comment: Welcome to [cryptography.se] Could you list some of them by [edit]ting into your question?

Comment: Consider participating? You earn 2 reputation points for accepting answers from others in case you haven't visited help center.

Answer (score 1):

This can be either a philosophical question or a empirical question, but answer to both these sides can be similar.

First, the title is correct, higher key sizes corresponds to a higher security level. **But** that's within the same cryptosystem.

Second, public-key cryptosystems are based on mathematical problems, whose solutions admit more efficient cryptanalytic algorithms than brutal-forcing their symmetric-key counterparts:

- RSA has GNFS,
- Lattice-based ones have BKZ,
- Hash-based signatures trades total number of messages that can be signed with signature size.

Elliptic-Curve Discrete Logarithm comes the closest to comparable with symmetric-key crypto, with Pollard's rho giving half the security level against the order of the base point of the elliptic curve group.

Third, even symmetric-key algorithms have hidden costs that people often assume only public-key algorithms have.

For example, the size of the key schedule of a block cipher, the number of rounds of a permutation, the total number of pre-computed constants, etc.

Comment: nice answer. of course the assumption is that the cryptosystem is correctly implemented and the keys are randomly generated from a uniform distribution or some very close approximation to this